# Obtain current date and time from remote windows computer on linux via telnet or smbclient

Tags: bash, dos, datetime

Is there a way to get current date and time from remote windows machine on linux?
On remote windows machine ssh not enabled, there are no powershell.
Can we achieve result via telnet or smbclient?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the net time command (net is part of SAMBA):

net time -S computername

(the same way you would use net time \computername from Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You must install time service on the remote computer (AFAIR, Windows has built-in time service).

Comment: thank you for response, friend.
Can you give some examples, please.